# docker-compose wait on other service before build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dependencies

There are a few approaches to fix container startup order in [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), e.g.

- [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on)
- [docker-compose-wait](https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait)
- [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31746182/89391) (Asked 7 years, 6 months ago, Modified 7 months ago, Viewed 483k times)
- ...

However, if one of the services in a docker-compose file includes a [build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) directive, it seems docker-compose will try to build the image first (ignoring `depends_on` basically - or interpreting `depends_on` as start dependency, not build dependency).

Is it possible for a `build` directive to specify that it needs another service to be up, before starting the build process?

Minimal Example:

```yaml
version: "3.5"
services:
  web:
    build: # this will run before postgres is up
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.setup # needs postgres to be up
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ...
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10
    ...
```

Notwithstanding the general advice that programs should be written in a way that handles the unavailability of services (at least for some time) gracefully, are there any ways to allow builds to start only when other containers are up?

---

Some other related questions:

- [multi-stage build in docker compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53093487/89391)

---

**Update/Solution**: Solved the underlying problem by pushing all the (database) setup required to the `CMD` directive of a bootstrap container:

```
FROM undertest-base:latest

...

CMD ./wait && ./bootstrap.sh
```

where [wait](https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait) waits for postgres and `bootstrap.sh` contains the code for setting up the postgres database with fixtures so the over system becomes fully testable after that script.

With that, setting up an ephemeral test environment with database setup becomes a simple `docker-compose up` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for this in Compose, and also it won't really work.

The output of an image build is a self-contained immutable image.  You can do things like `docker push` an image to a registry, and Docker's layer cache will avoid rebuilding an image that it's already built.  So in this hypothetical setup, if you could access the database in a Dockerfile, but you ran

```bash
docker-compose build
docker-compose down -v
docker-compose up -d --build
```

the `down -v` step will remove the storage the database uses.  While the `up --build` option will cause the image to be rebuilt, the build sequence will skip all of the steps and produce the same image as originally, and whatever changes you might have made to the database won't have happened.

At a more mechanical layer, the build sequence doesn't use the Compose-provided network, so you also wouldn't be able to connect to the database container.

There are occasional use cases where a dependency in `build:` would be handy, in particular if you're trying to build a base image that other images in your Compose setup share.  But neither the stable Compose file v3 [`build:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) block nor the less-widely-supported Compose specification [`build:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/) supports any notion of an image build depending on anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I included an "update" section in my question with the path that we choose.